# Is it possible to detect temporary objects at compile time?

Tags: c++, type-traits, temporary-objects

Is it possible to detect a temporary object at compile time with a type traits, something similar to `std::is_reference`, `std::is_lvalue_reference` and `std::is_rvalue_reference`, but specifically for temporaries, e.g. `is_xvalue_reference` (maybe in Boost or other libraries)?

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you want to know, e.g. with an example. Do you want to know whether a given expression materializes a temporary? `is_xvalue_reference` doesn't work, because "*xvalue references*" do not exist.

Comment: Why? I suspect [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Would `!std::is_lvalue_reference` suffice?

Comment: @rustyx it can return true and doesn't have to be temporary object. So this is necessary condition, but not sufficient.

Comment: Can you give an example of a temporary object you would like to perform this determination for?